# PsExec Fails to Execute with Error Code -1073741502

Tags: windows-10, command-line, psexec, windows-server-2019

whenever I want to run the following command in a remote server inside of our LAN with `PsExec`, it gives me the following error. It doesn't matter what I put instead of `cmd`, too. My macine's OS is Windows 10 and the remote server's is Windows Server 2019. If I don't use `-i` switch, it'll work but I don't want the session return:

```
PsExec.exe \\remoteServerName -u domain\user -p password -i cmd
```

Output:

```
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

cmd exited on iraryabizagi with error code -1073741502.
```

Comment: The error code -1073741502 == 0xC0000142 means NT_STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED. Dunno how it happens though, sorry.

Comment: ...and [it means](http://www.stbsuite.com/support/virtual-training-center/nt-status-errors) that "_a dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed_".

Comment: try with the `-h` and/or the `-d` switches after psexec

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a session ID after -i.
You can get one by running command below:

```
quser /SERVER:remote_machine

PsExec.exe -s -i **1** \\\remote_machine cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

`PsExec -i 0` solved for me a similar problem. I tried `-i 1` too, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).